# Z Notation: sequence of sequences - find sum

Tags: formal-methods, z-notation

Let me just say that this is for a university project. I do not expect an answer but more of a "hint".

I have a schema of a Supermarket that holds a sequence of queues:

```
+-- Supermarket-------
|queues: seq Queue
----------------------
```

And here is how I've defined a queue:

```
+-- Queue ----------
|length: ℕ
--------------------
```

I wish to define a schema that returns the total number of customers, waiting in line. Thus far I have:

```
+--TotalQueueCustomers----
|Ξsupermarket: Supermarket
|totalCustomers!: ℕ
|-------------------------
|totalCustomers = total θ supermarket
--------------------------
```

I'm struggling with defining the `total` function. It needs to "loop" every customer in every queue and sum their `length`s. Here is what I have so far: `total = q: Queue ⦁ q.length ↦ q.length`

Any idea?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Z notation, but looking [here](https://staff.washington.edu/jon/z/glossary.html) I believe you can do something in the spirit of $\text{total } s = \text{if } s = \langle\rangle \text{ then } 0 \text{ else } (\text{head } s).\text{length} + (\text{total tail } s)$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of the Z notation but here's what you have to do:
step 1: initialize a variable total to 0
step 2: loop through all queues
step 3: add the length of every queue to total

Answer (score 1):

To specify the $\mathit{TotalQueueCustomers}$ operation it helps to know that, in Z (and VDM and B), a sequence is a function from a finite prefix of the positive integers to the element type. Here your element type is $\mathit{Queue}$. To express the sum of the $\mathit{length}$ components of all the $\mathit{Queue}$s in your $\mathit{queues}$ you would want to write the Z-equivalent of this big sum in mathematics: $$\sum_{i=1}^{\#\mathit{queues}}\mathit{queues}(i).length$$
where $\# s$ is the length of sequence $s$ and $z.a$ is component $a$ of schema $z$. Your operation becomes the following.

```
+-TotalQueueCustomers------------------------------------------------
| ΞSupermarket
| totalCustomers!: ℕ
|--------------------------------------------------------------------
| totalCustomers! = Σi ∙ (1 ≤ i ≤ #queues | queues(i).length)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that it includes just two copies of `Supermarket`, the plain one and a primed one. No need to give them new names (as you did with `supermarket`).